# How to run a complete package in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace package first_pckg IS
PROCEDURE print_name;
FUNCTION ret_eid return number;
END;
create or replace PACKAGE BODY FIRST_PCKG IS
ename employees.first_name%type;
eid employees.employee_id%type;
PROCEDURE print_name is
BEGIN
select first_name into ename from employees where employee_id=100;
dbms_output.put_line(ename);
END;
Function ret_eid return number is
BEGIN
select department_id into eid from employees where employee_id=100;
return eid;
END;
END;
```

We can execute procedures and functions in packages using execute first_pckg.print_name

can someone let me know how to execute entire package once?

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "execute entire package once"? If you mean "execute all of the routines in the package with a single statement", then that is not something that can be done with Oracle packages. You could certainly bundle the calls into a single anonymous block and have them run one after another. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Package is an object which contains the logically related variables, constants, cursors and exceptions. A package contains procedures, functions which can be called. The are all grouped together for easy functionality and better performance. We cannot directly execute a package. We create a procedure in the package called as a main which would execute the complete package (which means the other procedures or functions based on the functionality)

Comment: A package is a library unit, like a module in C or Perl. You wouldn't "execute an entire module" in those languages, so not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package *declares* types, functions and procedures: It basically represents a repository of definitions and code. 'Executing' a package does not make much sense in general.

However, packages come with optional initialisation code which will be executed the first time a symbol from the package is referenced during a db session. In your example:

```
create or replace package first_pckg IS
    PROCEDURE print_name;
    -- ...
    Function ret_eid return number is
    BEGIN
        select department_id into eid from employees where employee_id=100;
        return eid;
    END;

BEGIN
    -- package init code goes here ...
END package;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it now.